# Is there a way to get the information on the current clipboard in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, clipboard

I wanted to get the information on the Windows clipboard which was set before running a program or application, but I couldn't find a way. Is there a way to get the information on the current clipboard in either C# or C++?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Notably, what research have you done so far? What have you attempted?

Comment: Yes, there certainly is.

Comment: Cmon....[Clipboard Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

In c# you can use the `Clipboard` class: [Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=net-5.0)

Here is how you can check if there is data and retrieve it:

```cs
bool IsHTMLDataOnClipboard = Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.Html);

// If there is HTML data on the clipboard, retrieve it.
string htmlData;
if(IsHTMLDataOnClipboard)
{
    htmlData = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);
}
```

Comment: I have edited your answer. We know it is unlikely the link from the documentation would be missing/dead, but try to avoid link only answers.

Comment: You are right, didn't think about that. Thanks!

Comment: I copied a string from the outside and tried `string str = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);` and `string str = Clipboard.GetText();`, but neither of them worked; they returned NullReferenceException. I wonder what I'm missing.